# Rotation to obtain corodinate

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given: $x0$ , $y0$, $x1$ and $y1$  points and angle $A$.

How to compute $x2$ in the figure specified.

Sorry if the questions seems trivial. I have forgot much of geometry.

Comment: If $x_2$ is given, there is no need to compute it, please fix the problem statement.

Comment: My guess is that he meant "given $x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1$"

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Please check now.

Comment: @angryavian Yeah that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle $B$ between vertical and $P_0P_1$ is such that $(x_1-x_0)=(y_1-y_0)\tan B$. And similarly, $(x_2-x_0)=(y_1-y_0)\tan(A+B)$.

Then

$$x_2=x_0+(y_1-y_0)\tan(A+\arctan\frac{x_1-x_0}{y_1-y_0}).$$

Using the tangent addition formula, this can be written

$$x_0+(y_1-y_0)\frac{\tan(A)+\frac{x_1-x_0}{y_1-y_0}}{1-\tan(A)\frac{x_1-x_0}{y_1-y_0}}=x_0+(y_1-y_0)\frac{(y_1-y_0)\tan(A)+(x_1-x_0)}{(y_1-y_0)-\tan(A)(x_1-x_0)}.$$

Comment: what is angle B here?

Comment: This is explained.

Comment: Should this work also in the case $x_2$ is to left of $x_1$. That is $x_2$ < $x_1$

Comment: Why not ? Angles can be signed. Did you try it before asking ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the law of cosines. Given your angle you will need to know 2 sides to the left and right of it. which can be found given the your points and the Pythagorean Theorem.